# Squeel subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

I am trying to use a subquery to select the latest status of some records.  I have the following query in SQL which I'd like to recreate in Rails using the squeel gem:

```
SELECT * FROM
changerequests c JOIN
    (SELECT changerequest_id,  max(created_at) max_created_at from 
     changerequest_statuses 
     GROUP BY changerequest_id) as max_status
ON c.id = max_status.changerequest_id
JOIN changerequest_statuses cs
ON cs.changerequest_id = c.id and max_status.max_created_at = cs.created_at
JOIN dim_change_statuses dcs
ON dcs.id = cs.dim_change_status_id
```

Following the guide here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#joins I have the following subquery:

```
subquery = ChangerequestStatus.group(:changerequest_id).select { [changerequest_id, max(created_at).as(max_date)] }
```

That works.  However joining it up to the Changerequest model I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'changerequest_id' for #<Hash>` error

```
Changerequest.joins{[changerequest_statuses, subquery.as('max_status').on { id == max_status.changerequest_id}]}
```

This looks like identical syntax to me. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating these scopes solved the problem:

In ChangerequestStatus.rb:

```
scope :max_id, -> {select('MAX(id) as max_id').group(:changerequest_id).map(&:max_id)}
```

In Changerequest.rb:

```
scope :max_condition, -> {where('changerequest_statuses.id IN (?)', ChangerequestStatus.max_id)}
```

It's only a partial solution because it only works with IDs not dates, and assumes later dated records will always have higher IDs which won't always be the case.